# How to manipulate the GL.bindframebuffer to target to bind GL_EXT_framebuffer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opengl, opentk, monogame

I'm trying to change the framebuffer object from `GL_ARB_framebuffer` and force it to use `GL_EXT_framebuffer` since my system is not compatible with the first one. Where in the solution do I need to implement this and how?

More information on my problem:

whenever I create a new Windows OpenGL project from Visual Studio using MonoGame I get the error `cannot find entry point in glbindframebuffer in opengl32.dll` since the framebuffer it uses is `GL_ARB_framebuffer` which is only supported in Opengl 3 so in a github post I read [Gihub post where they suggest this patch](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/998) that in order to patch you need to force the frame buffers to use `GL_EXT_framebuffer` but I don't know how to force them to use the EXT instead of the ARB , btw I'm using Opengl v2 Mobile intel 4 series card, which is Opengl v2 and ARB needs Opengl v3.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you have code that's working on one system but not on another? Please post the code. Or are you asking how to use framebuffer objects in general? Also you forgot to mention which version of OpenGL you are using.

Comment: whenever I create a new Windows OpenGL project from Visual Studio using MonoGame and compile i get the error "cannot find entry point in glbindframebuffer in opengl32.dll" since the framebuffer it uses is GL_ARB_framebuffer which is only supported in Opengl 3 so in a github post i read [link](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/998) that in order to patch you need to force the frame buffers to use GL_EXT_framebuffer but I dont know how to force them to use the EXT instead of the ARB one sorry for long comment, btw Im using Opengl v2 Mobile intel 4 series card.

Answer (score 0):

opentk has an 'ext' namespace:

```
gl.ext...
```